# java 3d error showing canvas and context creation error

Tags: java, 3d

```
DefaultRenderingErrorListener.errorOccurred:
CONTEXT_CREATION_ERROR: Renderer: Error creating Canvas3D graphics context
graphicsDevice = Win32GraphicsDevice[screen=0]
canvas = javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D[canvas0,10,10,380x450]
Java 3D ERROR : Canvas3D_createNewContext: Failed in SetPixelFormat - The pixel format is invalid.


Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 18 seconds)
```

The code is working in my PC.But its not working in my laptop , I have re-installed again all still I don't know wat changes to be made to work my code.

Comment: Maybe your laptop does not support the pixel format requested?